# Finding min and max dates SQL

Tags: sql, max, min

I would like to create a query where I find the details only for members with the earliest and latest registration_date.  So far I have

```
SELECT member_id, UPPER(name), registration_date 
from db.member WHERE registration_date >=
'2012-01-01'
```

I am unsure how to find just min/max but am just testing it with the set date 2012-01-01

So the query should only bring back two results - min/max

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get `min` , `max` dates in a subquery and then can get the results.

```
select member_id, upper(name), registration_date
from db.member
cross join (
       select min(registration_date) as minDate, max(registration_date) as maxDate
       from db.member ) t
where registration_date in ( t.minDate, t.maxDate)
```

or you can do it with `in` and `union`

```
select member_id, upper(name), registration_date
from db.member
where registration_date in  (
       select min(registration_date) 
       from db.member
       union 
       select max(registration_date) as maxDate
       from db.member )
```

Comment: In the off chance that the min and max dates have multiple identical timestamps/dates (depending on what your column datatype is), you should sort your min subquery by registration_date by ascending and grab the top 1, and for the max subquery, sort by registration_date descending and grab top 1 to ensure you do not get more than two records. Do this in the subqueries, if you do it in the outer query you run the risk of possibly getting 2 mins or 2 maxes.

Answer (score 0):

select min(dateColumn),max(dateColumn) from tbl;

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, while a little sub-query-heavy, might give you closest to what you need. Depending on the flavor of your SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc...) you can limit the subqueries for the member_id selects inside of the IN result set subqueries.

```
select member_id, Upper(name) AS name, registration_date 
from db.member 
where member_id in
(
    select Min(member_id) 
    from db.member
    where registration_date =
    (
        select Min(registration_date)
        from db.member
    )
    union all
    select Max(member_id) 
    from db.member
    where registration_date = 
    (
        select Max(registration_date)
        from db.member
    )
)
order by registration_date desc;
```